# How to make a modern website which deals good with IE7?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7, cascade-framework

I have done few sites for my clients but I came to know these are not working very well in IE7, There are still 3% people using IE7 :( What is the super quick way to fix it. You can refer me to some article or some js solution. Please advice!

Comment: I think your question is overly broad.  There's no quick solution to *"solve all my IE7 problems"*, especially seeing how you tagged [tag:javascript], [tag:html] *and* [tag:css].  If I were you, I'd post separate, more specific questions targeting problem areas of your site in IE 7.

Comment: Yes you are right, but this is very basic/general question. Like, Do I need to use some script like modernizr or may be separate css for IE.

Comment: I found js called ie7.js and not sure about it: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/  some one claimed it fix all issues. Any one use it before?

Comment: the answer could be both or neither, it depends on the problems you're having.  Stack Overflow isn't the place for general questions (try http://chat.stackoverflow.com for general discussion).  There's not going to be a correct answer to this question, all of the current answers just give you *"tips"* on how you *might* solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[www.modernizr.com/](http://www.modernizr.com/)

It doesn't get more super quick that this. Just remember to place it at the beginning of your scripts (in the head)

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure your sites are not in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) (ie have a valid doctype at the start of the html)
2. Use a Javascript framework to hide the browser differences.  There are several options, but [MooTools](http://mootools.net) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) are good choices

If you're lucky, it might even work in IE6.

Comment: an upvote for `doctype`! As far as the IE6 is concerned, don't think about it. I even can suggest you do your websites intentionally crash the IE6 ))

Comment: don't forget that there should be no white-space before the doctype, especially in IE.

Comment: yes for IE6 there is no problem but for IE7 we still have to support it :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a CSS framework that supports IE7.

For instance, try [Cascade Framework](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/). It supports IE from IE6 upwards, is about as feature rich as Bootstrap and has a grid system more flexible than any other grid systems around.